# C# Sockets byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, bitconverter

Okay so i'm receiving bytes from a request..

I call to read the bytes

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int resp = socket.Receive(buffer);
```

If I use this,

```
 Console.WriteLine(resp)
```

it returns a integer of 9, meaning 9 bytes are received

when I use

```
 int byte1 = buffer[0];
 Console.WriteLine(byte1);
```

it returns

```
0
```

so then when I use

```
        long bytelong = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(bytelong);
```

I would expect

```
 0( + other 7 bytes from the array )
```

but what I receive is

```
 -1249284928492
```

which is wrong, because I know the first byte is

```
0
```

Really confused with this..

Comment: Can you add the first 8 bytes you are receiving

Comment: You may want to use `BitConverter.ToUInt64` and display the value as hex for more clarity: `Console.WriteLine ("{0:X}", bytelong);`

Comment: `-1249284928492` as an 8-byte hex number is `FFFFFEDD20D0CC14`. In other words, the LSB is 0x14, and so your `byte[]` cannot possibly contain `0` at the first element. So the information you've provided in your post is simply incorrect. Either your array starts with the value 0, or passing it to `ToInt64()` returns `-1249284928492`. Both statements cannot be true at the same time. You need to provide at a minimum, a logically consistent question, and really you should be providing a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well then @PeterDuniho why does 

int byte1 = buffer[0];

return 0...?

Comment: _"why does int byte1 = buffer[0]; return 0"_ -- if you really get the number `-1249284928492` when you call `ToInt64()`, then it does not return 0. I don't know why you think it does, but as I've already said: the two statements are simply not possibly both true. Either the first byte in the array is 0, or the number returned when you call `ToInt64()` is `-1249284928492`. Since you haven't provided a code example demonstrating your claimed behavior, it's not possible to identify where your observation went wrong. But I guarantee you that it has.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know from the information given exactly what your specific problem is, but here's some general advice for debugging network communications that may help.

The most important thing is to be able to see exactly what data is being sent and received, before it is interpreted and converted by the application(s). The best way to do this is with external line monitoring software such as [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/). If you're going to be doing a lot of this, get familiar with a tool like that.

But for most jobs that's probably overkill. Just log the actual bytes that you're sending and receiving **before** you convert them, for example:

```
var count = socket.Receive(buffer);
Console.WriteLine("Received {0} bytes: {1}", count, BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, count));
```

Secondly, be aware of [byte ordering issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) when interpreting a byte stream as binary integers. If you don't know for certain that both sender and receiver will be using the same byte ordering, then consider using [Network Byte Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.networktohostorder?view=netframework-4.7.2) (aka Big Endian) for your multi-byte binary values.

For example, assuming your c# socket app is running on Windows, your 64-bit integer value is likely going to be stored as little endian:

```
long le_value = 0x0807060504030201; // "01-02-03-04-05-06-07-08"
long be_value = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(le_value); // "08-07-06-05-04-03-02-01"
```

To convert a received network byte order value back to little endian:

```
ulong le_value = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(be_value);
```

Hope that helps.